# Missing Release Files for Gnome3-Team PPA's, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, kernel, ppa, 22.04

I have a computer where Ubuntu 22.04 was installed from scratch (i.e. not upgraded to from an earlier version of Ubuntu). Any time I ran `sudo apt-get update` I would get errors for both of the `gnome3-team` PPA's for Jammy Jellyfish:

```
Ign:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                      
Ign:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:23 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This seemed very odd to me as they are not pointing to an earlier version of Ubuntu. All suggestions online said to simply remove the PPA's, but I am trying to compile a kernel from scratch on this machine which requires `kernel-package`, and when I attempt to obtain this via `sudo apt-get install kernel-package`, I get the error:

```
Package kernel-package is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kernel-package' has no installation candidate
```

I cannot find anything online in regards to this package being deprecated in newer versions of Ubuntu, so it stands to reason that the package cannot be found because of the removal of the `gnome3-team` PPA's previously. Are there release files located somewhere that I can download to fix this issue? Are these problems indeed correlated? Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing here "stands to reason", all the opposite. The Gnome3 PPA isn't updated since 2018 therefore has no content for Ubuntu 22.04 and for that reason alone it gives the error messages. Yes, of course it should be removed. The package `kernel-package` isn't available for Ubuntu 22.04 and has nothing to do with the PPA.

Comment: A quick search for "kernel-package" on https://packages.ubuntu.com for "all" versions returns only [Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) and Ubuntu Focal (20.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kernel-package&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Either the package has been replaced by another similar package or this package simply does not yet exist for 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

This ppa is out of date and has not been updated for any Ubuntu version newer than Ubuntu Bionic (18.04). You can verify this [on the launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) (google the ppa name to find the launchpad page). Scroll down to where it says "published in" and click the dropdown menu to show the available release versions of Ubuntu.

[image]

---

##### You have three options.

**Option 1** – you can remove the ppa by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt update
```

**Option 2** – you can reinstall Ubuntu using Ubuntu version 18.04 (not recommended).

**Option 3** – you could create a new partition and install Ubuntu to the third partition. Although you wouldn't have access to the ppa from your current Ubuntu install, you would be able to use the ppa from the newly installed version (also not recommended).

The last two options seem like overkill.

Comment: It appears that the package I was looking for did indeed get dropped in Ubuntu versions past 20.04. My mistake was assuming it had to do with the PPA's, as I could not find information about the package not being available in 22.04 and so concluded that had to be the cause (since they were PPA's from a fresh install of Ubuntu). My mistake.

Comment: @LeighK Yeah, you can search for non-ppa packages at https://packages.ubuntu.com However, since it's "referred to by another package" you might get a result using `apt-cache search kernel-package` to find out what replaces it.

Comment: @LeighK It looks like there isn't really a replacement as a few of the commands from `kernel-package` are not found in any other packages. However, there are other guides to build your own kernel that don't use the `kernel-package` method. I'm not sure how up to date this guide is but there is [this one here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). In the past, I've compiled my own kernel in order to use a scheduler unavailable on Ubuntu but I don't remember where I obtained the instructions.

Comment: That package was required for the presence of the subpackage make-kpkg. It seems that was also retired. I need it for an RT kernel build of xenomai which is following an install script for a GitHub repot called RTXI. Everything I have read so far seems to imply that deb-pkg is the route to go to replace that package. Apparently the kernel developers use that method and make-kpkg has been retired. So I just need to figure out how to use that instead. The call to that passes arguments that are not applicable to deb-pkg. I appreciate the heads up though! Many thanks :)